# how do I dynamically enter commands in oc debug mode in linux

Tags: linux

I have a commands in script which I have to execute one by one after oc debug  command

```
1. chroot /host
2. pxctl credentials create --provider s3 --s3-access-key <access_key> --s3-secret-key <secret-key> --s3-endpoint <endpoint> --s3-region <region> --bucket gunx my-s3

after oc debug <node>
Creating debug namespace/openshift-debug-node-9w ...
Starting pod/1898067876-debug ...
To use host binaries, run `chroot /host`
Pod IP: XX.XX.XX.XXX
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
sh-4.2#
```

I have to enter above commands(#1,#2) manually, is there a way to dynamically call above commands, without any manual intervention?

Answer (score 1):

In my case larsks' solution did not work for me, as I was already looping through my nodes. I just separated the two commands with spaces and it seems to work:

```
oc get nodes -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name | sed 1d | while IFS= read -r nodename; do oc debug node/$nodename -- chroot /host journalctl -xe -n 25 --no-pager ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your commands as input to `oc debug`, for example:

```
cat <<EOF | oc debug node/mynode
chroot /host
pxctl ...
EOF
```

You can also run arbitrary images using `oc debug`, so you could just pack up your scripts as the `ENTRYPOINT` of a docker image and run:

```
oc debug --image docker.io/myname/myimage node/mynode
```

Comment: using these commands in linux shell script, its greying out rest of the script of I use
     cat <<EOF | oc debug node/mynode
     chroot /host
     pxctl ...
     EOF

     warning: here-document at line 77 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
     syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: It sounds like you have a syntax error in your text file. You're welcome to post it (e.g. by editing your question) so that we can help you with it; otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: yes, you are correct, it has many blank space in between commands, It worked after I removed.

cat <<EOF | oc debug node/mynode 
chroot /host 
pxctl ... 
EOF

thank you for your help!